# pip install -U sec-edgar-downloader ERROR

Tags: python-3.x, object, module, pip, typeerror

Help!
Trying to install pip install -U sec-edgar-downloader   from  https://pypi.org/project/sec-edgar-downloader/
and got a message 
C:\Users\igcre>pip install -U sec-edgar-downloader

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

WHat should i do?

Comment: use  `python -m pip` instead of plain `pip`

Comment: thx, tried, new disaster  

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\lxml-4.2.5.dist-info\\INSTALLER'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Please don't add error messages in the comments. Rather add them as "update" to your question by hitting `edit`

Comment: But it looks like you need to run `cmd` with admin privileges

Comment: Thank you! great solution, they also ask to add -- user and then everyting works.